# RegEx include one string but not other in same regex

Tags: php, regex

So I am using directory iterator to get all php files like this:

```
$file_list = new RegexIterator($iterator_instance, '/^.+\.php$/');
```

Now `$file_list` contains all files having `.php` extension. However I want to be able to get all php files but **skip** folders with name **view** but I am not sure how to write such regex as I am not that good at it.

I just want to get all `.php` files but not from folder named **views**.

---

**Update:**

```
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator);
$file_list = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.php$/');
// foreach stuff now
```

Here I just want that from returned file/folder names, a folder named **views** should be skipped and I would love if above regex can be modified to account for that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
'%^(?!.*[\\\\/]views?[\\\\/]).+\.php$%'
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
(?!       # Assert that it's impossible to match the following here:
 .*       #  any number of characters
 [\\\\/]  #  a path delimiter (backslash or forward slash)
 views?   #  followed by view or views
 [\\\\/]  #  followed by a path delimiter
)         # End of lookahead assertion
.+        # Match one or more characters
\.php     # Match .php
$         # End of string
```

Comment: It isn't working when i run through updated code in my question. I am still getting views folder and files under it.

Comment: In your original question, the folders you wanted to skip were named `view`, not `views`. If you want to catch both, use `/views?/` in the lookahead assertion.

Comment: Thanks but it sill returns views folder. An example: `admin\views\includes\footer.php`. I want all php files but not from views folder that's actually want i am looking for.

Comment: OK, this regex matches `/` as path delimiters, you're using `\\`. No problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `CallbackFilterIterator` (PHP 5.4)

```
// Assuming $file_list is based on a FilesystemIterator
$iter = new CallbackFilterIterator($file_list, function($current) {
    return strpos('/views/', $current->getReaPath()) === false;
});
```

For PHP 5.3:

```
class DirectoryFilter extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return strpos('/views/', $current->getReaPath()) === false;
    }
}
$iter = new DirectoryFilter($file_list);
```

Comment: That's not my question ! I know that. It is about regex and skipping folder named **views** while using `RegexIterator` eg regex

Comment: @Dev555 I indeed mis read your problem. I have updated my answer again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I was preferably looking for regex solution. +1 though.